# Full text search with SPARQL queries in Amazon Neptune

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune

Most SPARQL endpoints have some extensions allowing for full-text search. Can I do full-text searches with the Amazon Neptune SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: documentation say no resp. it's not mentioned there. it's still beta status, either you ask the devs or you have to live with the slow regex of SPARQL.

Comment: @Reto Please see answer below. Is there any other info that you were looking for with regards to this?

Comment: @KarthikRajan I saw and upvoted the answer, leaving the question open in the hope somebody can give more infos on if and when to expect that feature. I guess an existing (large) Amazon customer would be in a better position to get more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neptune integration with Elasticsearch has been release with version `1.0.2.1`:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.0.2.1.html

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056182/1214125) for a detailed explanation or check the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search.html).

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2018, full text search is not supported out of the box in Neptune (Gremlin and SPARQL). I would recommend opening a support case with Neptune to get more info around when to expect this feature.